# Laravel 4 authentication with email and ID

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

Basically I want to allow users to log in using their email address and password, but use an auto-incrementing ID as the Users table primary key.

[Some tutorials](http://www.codediesel.com/frameworks/simple-user-authentication-in-laravel-4/) seem to indicate this is very straight forward. But that doesn't seem to be working for me. For a start I've had to alter the User model to use "email" as the authentication identifier. This works, but sessions do not save (see below).

Users table migration file;

```
Schema::create("users", function ($table) {
  $table->increments("id");
  $table->string("email", 255)->unique();
  $table->string("password", 60);
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

User model file;

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
  protected $table = 'users';
  protected $hidden = array('password');

  public function getAuthIdentifier() {
    return $this->email;
  }

  public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->password;
  }

  public function getReminderEmail() {
    return $this->email;
  }
}
```

Logging in with;

```
Auth::attempt(array("email" => Input::get("email"), "password" => Input::get("password")), true);
```

...works (as in returns true). The session however does not save properly. Any subsequent requests aren't authenticated. I've tried different session drivers with no success.

If I add;

```
protected $primaryKey = "email";
```

to the User model, the sessions work. **But** that can't be right, as "email" is not that table's primary key, "id" is (and I would like to keep "id" as the primary key).

---

**Also:** The [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/security) seems to indicate that you don't have to do *anything* special to use "email" as the identifying column, as "email" is used [here](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users), but then the numeric ID is used [here](http://laravel.com/docs/security#manually). Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent all of yesterday trying to solve this, now today I've basically reverted the User model back to how it was to begin with;

```
public function getAuthIdentifier() {
  return $this->getKey();
}
```

...and it's working (I can log in with email/password, and my session keeps me logged in).

I don't know why this wasn't working yesterday. Something to do with the way the session hashes are created? I have no idea.